# Python, accessing list/ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

This is the output of one of my variables.

I am trying to access each f the elements. But I am not able to

```
a = [array([[[ 326.,   50.],
    [ 570.,   16.],
    [ 574.,  259.],
    [ 342.,  274.]]], dtype=float32)]
```

I tried converting this to ndarray. And when I do, a[0] or a[0][0] they are out of bounds. This is the type -->

```
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
a.shape --> (1, 1, 4, 2)
a.size --> 8
```

How do I access individual elements?

These are the co-ordinates in x,y axes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `a[()]` notation.

For example, `a[(0,0,0)]` will return you `array([ 326.,   50.], dtype=float32)`.

Comment: How do I further access the x co-ordinate and y co-ordinate separately? I mean, 321 and 50 separately in this case?

Comment: `a[(0,0,0,0)]` will give you 326.0, and `a[(0,0,0,1)]` will give you 50.0.